# Connection timed out reading and image from url

Tags: java, proxy

I'm trying to get an image from an url through a proxy:

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.google.es/images/srpr/logo11w.png"); //Example
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("proxy", 8080)); //Proxy address is http://proxy:8080
URLConnection conexión = url.openConnection(proxy);

conexión.connect();

Image imagen = ImageIO.read(url.openStream());
```

The problem is at `this.imagen = ImageIO.read(url.openStream());`:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
    at gui.Ventana.<init>(Ventana.java:34)
    at servicio.Servicio2.buscar(Servicio2.java:60)
    at data.Main.main(Main.java:20)
```

I have also tried using the `Authenticator class` adding `Authenticator.setDefault(new Autenticador(username, password));`

```
public class Autenticador extends Authenticator {

    private String usuario;
    private String password;

    public Autenticador(String usuario, String password) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {

            return new PasswordAuthentication(usuario, password.toCharArray());
        }
    }

}
```

And I still get the same error. Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: If you try to another URL of http not https, then will it work?

Comment: I tried too and didn't work.

Comment: Next, is your proxy hostname "proxy" valid? if valid, execute ping proxy on the computer you execute the above program. if you don't know ping, please comment.

Comment: It is valid. Works perfectly in other applications.

Comment: Uhmmm, I think your program is correct. So, the reason can't connect is wrong environment or proxy settings. And it's strange that stacktrace is Connection timed out instead of Connection refused.

Comment: Yes it's strange because I'm writing a Jersey client application to use through the same proxy and works fine.